# Adding custom message to existing package (Humble + Ubuntu22) fails

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I am trying to integrate an existing functioning package with a custom message(so far it has been divided to two projects).

I am failing when trying to modify the CMakeLists with the following interface:

```
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME} 
  ${msg_files} 
)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:213 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "myPackage" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a shared library
  created in source directory "/home/user/ros2_ws/src/inuros2".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:110 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)
```

My Cmake up to that point is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(myPackage)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")

  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)

endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(cv_bridge REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp_components REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

set (SOURCES
       ...
        )

set (INCLUDES
       ...
        )
    
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        ${INCLUDES}
        ${SOURCES}
        )

set(dependencies
        cv_bridge
        rclcpp
        ...
        )

ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${dependencies}
        )

rclcpp_components_register_node(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PLUGIN "Class::NodeName"
  EXECUTABLE MyPackageExecutable
)

set(msg_files
  "msg/Features.msg"
)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${msg_files}
)
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411859/adding-custom-message-to-existing-package-(humble-+-ubuntu22)-fails/) by [AibohphobiA](https://answers.ros.org/users/57608/aibohphobia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2023-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally speaking, you should not put messages in the same package as the code using it as a best practice.

... but if you want to, you need to add a few extra lines https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/ros2/CMakeLists.txt#L77-L78 (so make sure to build the messages before the libraries).

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1